# Is it possible to add two or more Facebook pages as administrator of a group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

Recently Facebook added the feature of "associated group" for a Facebook page, and this allows you to set a Facebook page as admin of a Facebook group.

But is there any way to add two or more Facebook pages as admin of a Facebook group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's possible and this is how to do it. Everytime you want to add a second, third, etc page as administrator, you go to that Facebook page, then to the groups tab, then you click in "link your group" and then from the list of groups you are an admin of, and you select the group you want your page to be admin of (a group which supposedly already have one page as admin already) by clicking in the "link" button next to it.